# Unable to convert Javascript object to Java Model

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

My Spring controller and client side Javascript code are as follows and for some reason the Javascript object is unable to reach the Spring controller in the Object form. My Controller code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addRating", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public EmployeeRating addRating(@ModelAttribute("employeeRating") EmployeeRating employeeRating) {  
    if(employeeRating.getId()==0)
    {
        employeeRatingService.addRating(employeeRating);
    }
    else
    {   
        employeeRatingService.updateRating(employeeRating);
    }

    return employeeRating;
}
```

My Javascript code below:

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'https://myrestURL/addRating',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
              'id':5,
              'name': 'Name',
              'rating': '1'
          },
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (result) {
             // CallBack(result);
             window.alert("Result: " + result);
          },
          error: function (error) {
              window.alert("Error: " + error);
          }
      });
```

The EmployeeRating object in Java has id, name and rating fields so there's no mismatch.

---

Updating the model class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/* 
 * This is our model class and it corresponds to Country table in database
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEERATING")
public class EmployeeRating {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;

@Column(name="name")
String name;    

@Column(name="rating")
long rating;

public EmployeeRating() {
    super();
}
public EmployeeRating(int i, String name,long rating) {
    super();
    this.id = i;
    this.name = name;
    this.rating=rating;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public long getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(long rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}   

}
```

Comment: Show the `EmployeeRating` class.

Comment: Note that in Spring, it's clearer to use the `consumes` attribute on the annotation rather than manually specifying the header value.

Comment: added the EmployeeRating class

Answer (score 1):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so `application/json`; The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

If you use `application/json`, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send `JSON` object.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript object to json text and stores it in a string.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://myrestURL/addRating',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
          'id':5,
          'name': 'Name',
          'rating': '1'
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (result) {
         // CallBack(result);
         window.alert("Result: " + result);
      },
      error: function (error) {
          window.alert("Error: " + error);
      }
  });
```